# How can i split a video into NxM tiles spatially?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, tile

I want to spatially cut a video to generate N x M files.

For example，I want to split the test.video into NxM tiles?

[Video tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4v5z.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ffmpeg and its [crop filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop).  You could simply call it 4 times, each time cropping out the tile you need.

Comment: Thank you!According to your instructions, I can cut it into four tiles on the server side. I also want to merge these tiles into a complete video on the client side.Do you know how to make it?Could you help me

Comment: You could use 2x vstack ffmpeg filter and then once hstack (or vice versa).  Or maybe also a nullsrc source filter for the original resolution and the use the overlay filter 4 times to put the tiles in their respective positions.

Comment: Thank you!I successfully achieved it.In addition, I would like to ask you, if I use ffmpeg to control the video code rate, when the code rate is larger than the original file, is its video quality higher than the original file?

Comment: Good to hear. Your original is a file with some bitrate.  You will never have a better quality than that, no matter what you do later.

Comment: Hi,now I meet a problem about that split video by time.For example,when I use `MP4Box -split 1 test.mp4`,I can't get correct number of the files.The video length is 171.839 seconds,but the files number I got is bigger than 172 when I split the video by 1 second.