# How to split video in python into 4 equal sections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video, split

Are there any libraries in python that allow the input of a video file and then output 4 equal quadrants of that video files (eg: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right)?

At the moment I have only seen examples that split the video in terms of length (eg: a 20 minute video into 5 minute sections)

I know its probably possible by using something like opencv to split the video into frames and then split each frame into 4 and the make the individual frames back into the video but I think this is very resource hungry and not the most efficient solution.

Any suggestions or examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about `OpenCV`. You don't need to split into frames. You can used `OpenCV` or `scikit-video` to read videos into 4 dimensional array `(height, width, frames, channel)`. Then once you have size of weidth and height, you can just extract 4 videos by indexing. e.g. if `(400,600, 122, 3)` is your video dimension, you can get 4 videos by:

```
v1=vid[:200,:300,:,:]
v2=vid[200:,:300,:,:]
v3=vid[200:,300:,:,:]
v4=vid[:200,300:,:,:]
```

You can find solution using `ffmpeg` on: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376779/how-can-i-split-a-video-into-nxm-tiles-spatially)

This may be memory-wise cheaper (specially required RAM) compared to `OpenCV` or `scikit-video` solution. But the solution I mentioned above using scikit-video is not computationally expensive.

[read/write videos with scikit-video](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html)